# Optimal method for tensor assignment on a "sparse" tensor for Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array of size `n` (where `n` is a part of symbolic shape tensor). This array shall have `0` in every region but few where it will be a variable `b_class`.

Here's a simple `Numpy` implementation of this, but in this case our array will have a fixed size `100` instead of tensor:

```
import numpy as np

index_array = [10, 99, 50, 70] 
n = 100
zero_array = np.zeros(100)

for b_class in range(0, 4):
    zero_array[index_array[b_class]] = b_class  # every class position is defined by index_array

print(zero_array)
```

This works perfectly for defined constants, but in our case `n` is a tensor, so is `index_array`, therefore `zero_array = K.zeros((n))` where `K` is `Keras.backend` and hence assignment of values in "Pythonic" manner will yield an error:

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment in
>   TensorFlow

## Question

I want to find a way to replicate a code in Keras-based backend alone without the use of `tf.Variable` and `tf.SparseTensor` so that it can be fully compatible with Keras.

Is there any way to perform the simple task of assigning values to a sparse tensor at specific indexes with just vectorized operations?

Thank you!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You could use [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) to apply the sparse updates. Here's an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n = tf.constant([100])
index_tensor = tf.constant([[10], [99], [50], [70]])
updates = tf.range(4, dtype=tf.float32)

out = tf.scatter_nd(indices=index_tensor,
                    updates=updates,
                    shape=n)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(out))
```